# How can I prevent IE from blocking a hover trigger with the child element?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser

I have some HTML and CSS code which works really well in every other browser except IE10 and below, surprise surprise. Basically, there's a user profile page with their profile picture (avatar).

When you hover over the avatar, some CSS tells a div inside the avatar div to change opacity from 0 to opacity 1. Inside that div, there's a Tweet button - embedded using an iframe and [Socialite,](http://socialitejs.com/) but that's irrelevant.

What happens in IE is that you'll hover over the avatar and the button will display as it's meant to, except when you hover over the Tweet button, it "blocks" the cursor from being on top of the avatar div, which causes it to disappear. This is an IE quirk, and it shouldn't act like this, as the outside trigger div is a parent of everything inside it.

Here's the HTML using [Handlebars:](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

```
<div class="profile-avatar" style="background-image:url({{avatar_url}})">
  <div class="avatar-overlay">
    <div class="tweet-profile">
      <a href="//twitter.com/share" class="socialite twitter-share" data-count="none" data-text="Check out my profile!" data-url="{{url}}" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS (it's [Stylus,](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/) so slightly stripped back syntax):

```
.profile-avatar
  @extend .background-cover
  height 120px
  margin-bottom 10px
  position relative

  &:hover
    .avatar-overlay
      opacity 1

.tweet-profile
  position absolute
  top 50px
  left 32px

  &:hover
    opacity 1

.avatar-overlay
  position absolute
  left 0px
  top 0px
  width 100%
  height 100%
  background-color rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
  opacity 0
  transition opacity 250ms
```

Comment: stylus! my eyes! gaahhhh they burn! where's some water to put them out, oh here it is SASSssssssss

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
 .profile-avatar .tweet-profile
    position absolute
    top 50px
    left 32px
    z-index 999999999

    &:hover
      opacity 1
```

Also, the hover on:

```
.profile-avatar
  @extend .background-cover
  height 120px
  margin-bottom 10px
  position relative

  &:hover
    .avatar-overlay
      opacity 1
```

Looks wrong, as it has a class inside the hover? I'd have to try it stylus myself, but I'd guess it would be:

```
 &:hover .avatar-overlay
   opacity 1
```

Comment: Yeah, z-index doesn't have any effect sadly.

Comment: That's what triggers it. So I'm saying, when you're hovering over element A, then change the opacity of A's child element, B.

Comment: this is a known issue with IE. you may have to resort to javascript to solve this one. i had a similar problem that i was able to solve with [pointer events](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) and some good ol'-fashioned JS